# Checking for null value in singleton pattern

Tags: java, android

I've found the following code in a [Google sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java), a simple `getInstance()` method implementation for a singleton:

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context, final AppExecutors executors) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) { // why do we check this?
                sInstance = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);
                sInstance.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

It's perfectly clear why we're checking `sInstance` for `null` the first time, but why do we check it inside the `synchronized` block as well?

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Note that singletons constructed using user-supplied parameters are fishy. What happens when you call the method a second time with different parameters? You *think* you got an instance using `context2`, but actually you have an instance using `context1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner isn't that the reason why `context.getApplicationContext()` is called?

Comment: OK, same point, with `executors1` vs `executors2`.